# Server open index in wrong direction

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a React app which I start from express server. I have public directiory with /public/index.html file and copy of that file in '/' directory.

Code:

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080
const app = express()

app.use(express.static(__dirname))

app.get('*', (req,res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, './public/index.html'))
})

app.listen(port)
console.log('Server started: '+ port)
```

My server.js file is in '/' directory.

Express opens index.html in '/' directory instead of one this one in public directory, any suggestions why ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public/')))`

Your `use` statement handles get requests first and makes `app.get(*` obsolete.